# Sort a list consisting of strings made up of strings and integers

Tags: c#, list

so I have a list in C# made up of strings that are made up of strings and integers. For example, 'Jim:50' or 'Ben:27'. I want to be able to sort this list using the integer, but I don't know where to start. My current code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class Leaderboard : MonoBehaviour {

    string path = "Assets/Statistics.json";

    public List<string> scoresList = new List<string>();

    void Start() {
        JSONUnpacker();
        scoresList.Sort(scoreSorter);
    }

    void JSONUnpacker() {
        // Read from json file
        string jsonData = File.ReadAllText(path);
        leaderboard leaderboard = JsonUtility.FromJson<leaderboard>(jsonData);
        foreach(var i in leaderboard.statDataList) {
            // Repeat for every stat record
            string temp = i.username + ":" + i.score;
            scoresList.Add(temp);
        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class leaderboardData {

        public string username;
        public int score;
    }

    private class leaderboard {

        public List<leaderboardData> statDataList = new List<leaderboardData>();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You seem to have a list of string, `scoreList` and a list of `leaderboardData`. Which one to you wan to sort?

Comment: `var sorted = scores.OrderBy(score => int.Parse(score.Split(':')[1]));`

Comment: Go on @RufusL, post that as an answer.

Comment: Why are you storing two variables in a `List<string>` using `i.username + ":" + i.score` rather than storing in a `List<(string UserName, int Score)>`?

Comment: I'm still kinda new to C#

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the number string and turn it into integer. For example if you are guaranteed to have format "letters" + ":" + "numbers" you can do something like that:

```
List<string> scoresList = new List<string>{"Jim:50","Ben:27", "John:28"};
var sorted = scoresList 
    .OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Substring(s.IndexOf(":") + 1)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining how that sort works? I'm still trying to learn

Comment: @DerpDiamonds `s.IndexOf(":")` returns index of `:` in string, `s.Substring(s.IndexOf(":") + 1)` gets the part of string after `:`, `int.Parse` parses string into integer.

Answer (score 0):

You must sort by property, not only Sort
E.g. `l.OrderBy(s => s.score)`
Also you could implement `IComparable` interface and .Sort will be working You could do it like

```
public class UserScore: IComparable<UserScore>
{
    public int Score {get; set;}

    public int CompareTo(UserScore other)
    {
        return Score.CompareTo(other.Score);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to external sites. An answer should be stand alone in case the link ever breaks.

Comment: @Enigmativity it is one of the first links in google. I'm pretty sure that it is not to hard to find any other IComparable implementation, because it is really common, no? But i've hard you , ok

Comment: It's a link to an external site. It doesn't matter where it comes from. You should show the implementation in your answer and only link to support the content you've written.

Comment: It is like my first day answering ppl questions and ok, i see you but, but not to friendly to downvote answer because external link in it. E.g. in another topic i was asked to host solution somewhere and i did it on github . It is external link too

Comment: I have been polite and friendly. I'm just letting you know the etiquette on the site. A good response would be for you to edit the question to show the implementation of `IComparable` and not to argue that you're new or that you've done something wrong elsewhere too. The quality of the questions and answers here is what makes the site so valuable and it's everyone's job to help improve the overall quality. That's all I'm doing.

Comment: @Enigmativity +

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating the list yourself, and then you want to sort it. I'd recommend doing the sorting before/as you are creating the list, which thanks to LINQ [`OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) can be done very easily:

```
foreach (var i in leaderboard.statDataList.OrderBy(x => x.score)) {
    // ...
}
```

Or if you need the opposite sort order, use [`OrderByDescending()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending):

```
foreach (var i in leaderboard.statDataList.OrderByDescending(x => x.score)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `Sort` you need to write a "comparer" class.

to compare `leaderboardData` write this:

```
 public class leaderboardDataComparer : IComparer<leaderboardData>
```

and use Quick Actions (Ctrl+.) to implement missing method.

```
 public int Compare([AllowNull] leaderboardData x, [AllowNull] leaderboardData y)
 {
 }
```

Then write your comparison logic:

```
 if (x.score > y.score) return 1;
 if (x.score < y.score) return -1;
 return 0;
```

to compare `string` data, write this:

```
public class leaderboardStringDataComparer : IComparer<string>
{
     public int Compare([AllowNull] string x, [AllowNull] string y)
     {
          var xscore = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(':')[1]);
          var yscore = Convert.ToInt32(y.Split(':')[1]);
          if (xscore > yscore) return 1;
          if (xscore < yscore) return -1;
          return 0;
     }
}
```

usage:

```
 scoresList.Sort(new leaderboardStringDataComparer());
```